# Run an os.popen command requiring pseudo terminal from python in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, python, expect

I have a python script which uses

```
size = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
```

to get the terminal window size so I can print text nicely. My problem arises when I have to run this python script through a bash script. I have a bash script which calls `rosrun` on this python script in the background (using &), and I get the error -

```
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

After looking around a bit, I understand this is because `stty` requires a terminal (or pseudo-terminal) and the bash script I am running is not providing it. I cannot use `sudo` as `ros` commands cannot be run with root user.

Using `script -q -c` command doesn't help either. Is there some way that I can fix this issue without having to change `os.popen` command in the python script to an alternative? Currently, I am thinking of perhaps adding a print before the os.popen and using `expect` in the bash script.

Comment: Perhaps in the bash script: `python program.py < /dev/tty` ?

Comment: Interesting, tried it and seems like it half fixes it. so the python script is calling this command in a loop rapidly and half the time it is working, but it is still throwing the same error the remaining half of the time. What could be the cause of this?